# Create a `data-win-control` in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, winjs

Is it possible to instantiate a data-win-control object in JavaScript without having to drop it onto the DOM and calling `WinJS.UI.processAll()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you can do it in code behind:

```
// Object is a new FlipView component instantiate in code behind
// element can be an element already existing in the DOM or just created with JS
var object = new WinJS.UI.FlipView(element, options);
```